# what's the object's type in Relationship between operation?

Tags: c++

i read the c++ primer, i found a example like this:

```
int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;

if(i < j < k)
    return 0;
```

we all know the result's type of Relationship between operation is bool, so "i < j"'s result is true. when the previous result and k to calculate, the previous result's type will change to int?

Comment: Related to [Is the operation “false < true” well defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26143976/1708801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `true` from `i < j` will be implicitly converted to `1`. Then `1 < k` yields `true` as well.

A `false` would be converted to `0`.